# ffmpeg: resulting video from timelapse not playable in quicktime after size change

Tags: ffmpeg

I can create a "timelapse" video from a series of photos using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -f image2 -framerate 24 -i "*.JPG" -r 24 -s uhd2160 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 disassembly-2.mp4
```

And this is playable by Quicktime. However, if I change the `-s` option to be `4000x3000` to exactly match the size of the photos, Quicktime can no longer play the resulting video. VLC can, but not QT.

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -f image2 -framerate 24 -i "*.JPG" -r 24 -s 4000x3000 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 disassembly-2.mp4
```

Does anyone know why this change alone would break playback in QT?

Running Mac OS 10.12.1 on a 2013 Mac Pro. QT is version 10.4 (891). ffmpeg is:

`ffmpeg version 3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
libavcodec     57. 64.100 / 57. 64.100
libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100`

Quicktime does not show an error message. It plays a video of the appropriate size (dimensions) and length of play that is entirely black.

Comment: If the images are already 4000x3000 then there is no need for `-s 4000x3000`. Also, `-r 24` is equally superfluous because you already declared `-framerate 24`: the output will automatically inherit the input rate.

Comment: I did try to leave off the `-s` and the resulting video was the same. Just wanted to share that the size was the only difference, explicitly. Thanks for the tip about framerate.

Comment: I can confirm the issue on QuickTime 10.4 on macOS 10.12.1, but will not have time to look into it until later today: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=d=3:s=4000x3000,format=yuv420p -c:v libx264 output.mp4`

Comment: Issue is likely due to [H.264 level limits](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22572790/1109017). WMP also fails to decode this.

Comment: That's most likely it. If you wanna set that as an answer, I'll accept it. I'll have to figure out how to use HEVC as suggested.

Comment: I was able to switch `-vcodec` to `prores` and the extension to `.mov` and QT will play it, and premiere will import it. This may be ill-advised for general usage, but what I needed to do is make a timelapse that I could edit. I can crop and output as uhd later on.